# How to use gurobi variable as input to a tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, model, gurobi

In a gurobi model, **I need to use a variable** (added through addVar) **as an input to a tensorflow model** (I used a simple model trained to follow the function: y = 2x+1) **which is then used in a constraint**.

The tensorflow model is already trained and loaded, I just need to use the predict method.

The optimization problem is the following: Get the best input for the tensorflow model so that the output prediction is closest to a given reference.

For example, if I want the prediction to be 11, the input of the model should be very close to 5 (2*5+1 = 11).
The way I have implemented this is by using an objective function of the absolute error between the reference value and the predicted one, by linealizing the abs() function to be able to use it in Gurobi.

The gurobi model is correct, the problem relies on using a gurobi variable as input to the tf model, because until the optimization problem has been solved, it has no defined value (giving it a Start value will not work).

This is the code for my model:

```
import gurobipy as gp

# Load tensorflow model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./models/test_model.h5')

mdl = gp.Model()
ref = 11 # desired output value

w = mdl.addVar(lb=-10, name='input')
a = ref # just for naming purposes
b = mdl.addVar(lb=-10,name = "b")
x = mdl.addVar(name='error') # variable needed to linealize abs() function

mdl.update()

# objective function is abs(ref - model.predict([w])[0][0])
mdl.setObjective(x, gp.GRB.MINIMIZE)

mdl.addConstr(w <= 10)
mdl.addConstr(w >= -10)

# mdl.addConstr(b == 2*w+1) # if I use this line instead of the next one, everything works but I am not using the tensorflow model
mdl.addConstr(b == model.predict([w])[0][0]) # does not work

# 3 constraints needed for the abs() linealization
mdl.addConstr(x >= 0)
mdl.addConstr(a - b <= x)
mdl.addConstr(b - a <= x)
mdl.update()

# Solve and show solution
mdl.optimize()
for v in mdl.getVars():
    print('%s %g' % (v.varName, v.x))
print('2w+1 =', 2*w.X+1)
```

And the error given is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6484/1577208091.py in <module>
     16 
     17 # mdl.addConstr(b == 2*w+1) # if I use this line instead of the next one, everything works but I am not using the tensorflow model
---> 18 mdl.addConstr(b == model.predict([w])[0][0]) # does not work
     19 
     20 # 3 constraints needed for the abs() linealization

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1718                         '. Consider setting it to AutoShardPolicy.DATA.')
   1719 
-> 1720       data_handler = data_adapter.get_data_handler(
   1721           x=x,
   1722           batch_size=batch_size,

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in get_data_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1381   if getattr(kwargs["model"], "_cluster_coordinator", None):
   1382     return _ClusterCoordinatorDataHandler(*args, **kwargs)
-> 1383   return DataHandler(*args, **kwargs)
   1384 
   1385 

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution, distribute)
   1135       self._steps_per_execution_value = steps_per_execution.numpy().item()
   1136 
-> 1137     adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)
   1138     self._adapter = adapter_cls(
   1139         x,

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in select_data_adapter(x, y)
    974   if not adapter_cls:
    975     # TODO(scottzhu): This should be a less implementation-specific error.
--> 976     raise ValueError(
    977         "Failed to find data adapter that can handle "
    978         "input: {}, {}".format(

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'gurobipy.Var'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>
```

However, if I use the line above the `b == model.predict([w])[0][0]` constraint, everything works ok and the solution found is indeed 5:

```
Gurobi Optimizer version 9.5.0 build v9.5.0rc5 (win64)
Thread count: 2 physical cores, 4 logical processors, using up to 4 threads
Optimize a model with 6 rows, 3 columns and 9 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0xc4fcfa7a
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e+00, 2e+00]
  Objective range  [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Bounds range     [1e+01, 1e+01]
  RHS range        [1e+00, 1e+01]
Presolve removed 4 rows and 1 columns
Presolve time: 0.01s
Presolved: 2 rows, 2 columns, 4 nonzeros

Iteration    Objective       Primal Inf.    Dual Inf.      Time
       0    0.0000000e+00   1.050000e+01   0.000000e+00      0s
       1    0.0000000e+00   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00      0s

Solved in 1 iterations and 0.04 seconds (0.00 work units)
Optimal objective  0.000000000e+00
input 5
b 11
error 0
2w+1 = 11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot pass a Gurobi variable to a TensorFlow model. These are vastly different software packages that are not interoperable like that. You should look into how to use [Gurobi callbacks](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/cb_codes.html) to see how you can call different codes from within a running optimization. Please note that you cannot modify the problem at will during the callback's execution.
You may also just try an iterative approach: optimizing to get the first estimate that you can then plug into Tensorflow and then optimize using the new information.

I am not sure what the goal of your approach is, so my suggestions may not be applicable to your idea.

**EDIT:** You may be able to use this tool for your application: [ReLU_ANN_MILP](https://github.com/ChemEngAI/ReLU_ANN_MILP)